# How can I apply discriminant analysis (multivariate) if my data is not normally distributed?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, discriminant-analysis

As LDA and QDA assume normality and homoscedasticity, and my data is not that well behaved ... is there any other kind of robust technique I could use?

Could applying box cox transformations and then applying LDA/QDA be a good solution?

Edit: I´ve read this question [Linear Discriminant Analysis and non-normally distributed data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/110908/linear-discriminant-analysis-and-non-normal-distributed-data?rq=1)

but the classification using LDA and QDA using the raw data misclassify with a 40 and 30% error rate.

Comment: You could use KNN, which doesn't make any assumptions about the shape of the data.

Comment: Applying LDA under no normality is quite common. I don't think transforming your data will much help in that regard, unless you have completely skewed data and really different scales in your features.

Comment: @Firebug. I need to improve my prediction as plain LDA is not working in my case. See the 30% error rate. Thanks!